# OneSignal React Native Push iOS Universal Linking (avoid WebView)

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-native-ios, onesignal

Using onesignal, When one sets the push notification value "url" for a notificaiton to open in an app, aka universal linking, by default the app is opened and a webview screen emerges (not on android, only iOS - at least in React Native).

I want to ignore this webview. I don't want to open it. The url is supposed to open the app to the corresponding universal link/deep link, not my domain on a web broswer. If I click on a similar link from a non-notificaiton source, it takes me to the screen, why does the push notification not do this?

How do I override this? I can't seem to figure it out. Do I have to manually implement this? Why does it open a webview by default and not the corresponding screen in the app instead?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to manually route it if one were to go this route, unfortunately. From what I'm gathering bits here and there.

this is a bad choice to go with if you're using iOS:

**https://www.myapp.com/p/fdsafa**

this is better:

**myapp://p/fdsafa**

unfortunately onesignal has it setup in some weird way with the https://www.myapp.com that it makes it useless on iOS, unless your actual intention is to open an actual web url in a webview. Where as myapp:// is compatible with both platforms (just don't put a host on Android, leave the host out, just do the myapp as the schema). Works.